# SQL TABLE to store lists of strings

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-design, db2, derby

I have to maintain some lists in DB (SQLServer, Oracle, DB2, Derby), I have 2 options to design underlying simple table:

1st:

**`NAME   VALUE`**
`dept      HR
 dept      fin
 role      engineer
 role      designer`

UNIQUE CONSTRAINT (NAME, VALUE) and some other columns like auto generated ID, etc.

2nd:

**`NAME   VALUE_JSON_CLOB`**
`dept   {["HR", "fin"]}`
`role   {["engineer", "designer"}]`

UNIQUE CONSTRAINT (NAME) and some other columns like auto generated ID, etc.

There is no DELETE operation, only SELECT and INSERT/UPDATE. In first advantage is only INSERT is required but SELECT (fetch all values for a given NAME) will be slow. In second SELECT will be fast but UPDATE will be slow. By considering there could be 10000s of such lists with 1000s for possible values in the system with frequent SELECTs and less INSERTs, which TABLE design will be good in terms of select/insert/update performance.

Comment: [First normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) dictates values should be atomic. Not comma separated, not json, just single value.

Answer (score 1):

The first table is in [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), which is the foundation of good relational design. Using a CLOB to store data is bad design, because it means you will need to unpack the array every time you need to reference an individual value or update the set of values: you can't use simple SQL statements.  It also means you can't use the values in constraints (foreign keys, unique constraints).

These are not just theoretical objections. Working with CLOBs will burn CPU every time you extract the individual elements.

The problem is you are trying to build a generic solution which works across multiple database flavours. This inevitably means you will end up with a sub-optimal design for some databases because performance features tend to be product specific. For instance, with an Oracle or MSSQL implementation an [Index Organized table](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) (aka clustered index) could be very helpful with the first table structure but Derby and DB2 don't have such a thing. Still a compound index on a regular heap table would be almost as good.

So what it comes down to is this: how likely is that you **will** be handling tens of thousands of lists with thousands of items? Will you always be working with **a whole set** rather than a sub-set of a list's values? Depending on those considerations you have a trade-off, ease of use (SQL manipulation) against the reduced I/O for a pre-assembled set.

Comment: Thankyou APC for the explanation. yes, I always need to work with the whole set of values for a list but updating one value at a time i.e. append in the existing list. Also I don't need any foreign keys, unique constraints on values if maintained in CLOB form.